# Resolve response header to a custom POJO

Tags: java, azure, jax-rs

Have an call to an API

And i create as of now a POJO to map the Json response

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public  class ResponseBricks<T>{

public ResponseBricks<T>(@JsonProperty("location") Location location,
        @JsonProperty("properties") Properties properties, 
         @JsonProperty("error") AzureError error) {

    this.location = location;
    this.properties = properties;
    this.error = error;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location  location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public T getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public void setProperties(T properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

public AzureError getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setErrorAzureError error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Response response) {
    this.response = response;
}



private Location location;
private T properties;
private String id;
private String name;
private AzureError error;
private Response response;
```

}

Now i need Headers from the response and thus included

```
private Response response;
```

However the Response isnt mapped to exactly the response from the azure call and the Response comes as null.
I can get headers if i keep the response as Response than my custom POJO.However is there any way to use the custom pojo with the response as a variable inside it?

Comment: I have used Response of jaxrs as of now where i can get response.getHeaders() but i want to know if theres a better way of having this header included in  a custom class like mine above?

Comment: So tried this out.The only way is to use Response.Custom Pojo for response wont give the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So tried this out.The only way is to use Response.Custom Pojo for response wont give the headers.
Response has many methods to not only get the headers but also the body.